# Address Field in Salesforce

Tags: opportunity, data-types, address

I want to have an address field on Opportunity.I know there is no Address data type.How to achieve something like a Standard Address field like Account's Billing Address.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrVWAA0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently supported for Opportunity - only the Account object has multiple Address standard fields, i.e. the Billing and Shipping Address. You can either create a set of Number/Text custom fields directly on Opportunity, or you can create a custom Address object and relate it to opportunity.